# Toggle parent of a DIV onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a code where I have a page divided into four columns/ lists. There are in total 32 list, but only the group of four are displaying at the same time.

Inside each column there are a list of DIV elements that contains a button. When the button is clicked, I want them to be moved. So if a DIV is located in "List3", I want it to be moved to "List1". And if it is located in "List4", I want it to be moved to "List2". This needs to be a toggle, so that I can swap back and forth.

I can get the script to  work no problem. What I am strugling with is when there are 35 list, and I have to specify an ID for each of the 32 lists, and soon to be even more.

Is there a way to specify that the DIV that will be moved always will go between L3-L1 and L4-L2. If so - that would save me the hassle of having to make a new script for each list that shoul all link in the same manner. Would love som help one this one!

See code below

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".moveBtn2");
    var list1 = document.getElementById("L1");
    var list2 = document.getElementById("L3");

    function moveItem(e) {
        var moveTo = this.parentElement.parentElement == list1 ? list2 : list1;
        moveTo.appendChild(this.parentElement);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", moveItem);
    }
}); 

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".moveBtn3");
    var list2 = document.getElementById("L2");
    var list4 = document.getElementById("L4");

    function moveItem(e) {
        var moveTo = this.parentElement.parentElement == list2 ? list4 : list2;
        moveTo.appendChild(this.parentElement);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", moveItem);
    }
});
```

```html
<div id="G235" class="topshort hidden">
<h2 class="test1" style="position: absolute; left: 22%">Bestått</h2>
<div class="div-left">
<br>
 <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Fellesfag</h3>
     <div class="boxy" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray; position: relative; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"><strong><br><i>Fag</i><i style=" position: absolute; right: 80px;">Karakter</i></strong></div>
 <div id="L1">
</div>
</div> 
<div class="div-leftleft">
  <br>
 <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Programfag</h3>
     <div class="boxy" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray; position: relative; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"><strong><br><i>Fag</i><i style=" position: absolute; right: 80px;">Karakter</i></strong></div>
 <div id="L2">

</div>
</div> 
<div class="vlshort"></div>
       
       <h2 class="test2" style="position: absolute; left: 71%;">Ikke bestått</h2>
       <div class="div-right"> 
<br>
      <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Fellesfag</h3>
           <div class="boxy" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray; position: relative; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"><strong><br><i>Fag</i><i style=" position: absolute; right: 80px;">Karakter</i></strong></div>
       <div id="L3">
<div class="lines">
   <a>Text</a>
   <button class="moveBtn2">Legg til</button>
      <hr>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
    
<div class="div-rightright">
  <br>
 <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Programfag</h3>
     <div class="boxy" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray; position: relative; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"><strong><br><i>Fag</i><i style=" position: absolute; right: 80px;">Karakter</i></strong></div>
 <div id="L4">
 <div class="lines">
   <a>Text</a>
   <button class="moveBtn3">Legg til</button>
      <hr>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<a style="position: absolute; left: 35px; bottom: 35px; color: grey;" contentEditable="true">IB = Ikke bestått</a>
    
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the needed IDs dynamically:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(!/\bmoveBtn/.test(e.target.getAttribute('class'))){
    return;
  }
  // get div to move
  const listToMove = e.target.closest('.lines').parentElement;
  const id = listToMove.id.match(/\d/)[0];
  const moveToId = `L${id - (e.target.dataset.moved ? -2 : 2)}`;
  const moveTo = document.querySelector(`#${moveToId}`);
  e.target.dataset.moved = !e.target.dataset.moved;
  moveTo.appendChild(e.target.parentElement);
});
```

```html
<div id="G235" class="topshort hidden">
<h2 class="test1" style="position: absolute; left: 22%">Bestått</h2>
<div class="div-left">
<br>
 <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Fellesfag</h3>
     <div class="boxy" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray; position: relative; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"><strong><br><i>Fag</i><i style=" position: absolute; right: 80px;">Karakter</i></strong></div>
 <div id="L1">
</div>
</div> 
<div class="div-leftleft">
  <br>
 <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Programfag</h3>
     <div class="boxy" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray; position: relative; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"><strong><br><i>Fag</i><i style=" position: absolute; right: 80px;">Karakter</i></strong></div>
 <div id="L2">

</div>
</div> 
<div class="vlshort"></div>
       
       <h2 class="test2" style="position: absolute; left: 71%;">Ikke bestått</h2>
       <div class="div-right"> 
<br>
      <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Fellesfag</h3>
           <div class="boxy" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray; position: relative; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"><strong><br><i>Fag</i><i style=" position: absolute; right: 80px;">Karakter</i></strong></div>
       <div id="L3">
<div class="lines">
   <a>Text</a>
   <button class="moveBtn2">Legg til</button>
      <hr>
  </div>
   </div>
</div>
    
<div class="div-rightright">
  <br>
 <h3 style="font-size: 16px">Programfag</h3>
     <div class="boxy" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: lightgray; position: relative; margin-bottom: 15px; border-bottom: solid; border-top: solid"><strong><br><i>Fag</i><i style=" position: absolute; right: 80px;">Karakter</i></strong></div>
 <div id="L4">
 <div class="lines">
   <a>Text</a>
   <button class="moveBtn3">Legg til</button>
      <hr>
  </div>
</div>
</div> 
<a style="position: absolute; left: 35px; bottom: 35px; color: grey;" contentEditable="true">IB = Ikke bestått</a>
    
     </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt, Alexander. Unfortunately the script is unable to calculate the dynamic ID's of my list. I have a list of maybe 15 DIV elements in each column that needs to be moved. The script moves only the first element, after two clicks and to the wrong column. It moves from column 3-4 instead of 3-1.

Comment: @Cosmochen my snippet works fine, you asked the behavior, i've provided. so my answer is correct. seems the problem is in incorporating the snippet into your project. that happens regardless of the answer being correct.